# How to trigger a seque between iOS view controllers?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am a beginner.

I have linked two view controllers together with a segue (push). How do I now trigger that push, so it transitions from one view to another? There was no method added in my implementation file which I find weird as it does happen when I create a button or alike.

[image]

Comment: Show us the screenshot of your storyboard with segue that you have created.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/bROjl

Comment: you are in the right way , if you use the push in segue, just embed the initial VC with navigation controller, see this tutorial https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/navigation-controllers-and-view-controller-hierarchies--mobile-14052

Comment: @konyv12 Embed the In the App scene to `NavigationController` the in your button action simply call the `performSegue` with your segue identifier.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to go to the storyboard file, select segue and give it an `identifier`

[image]

then in your `UIViewController` call:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "account", sender: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you took the segue in your storyboard, you must have given an idenfier so put that identifier here in the perform segue with identifier. And you are done.

```
@IBAction func nextVC(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("nextVC", sender: sender)
}
```

Put this code on the button action on which you want to segue your next ViewController. Hope it helps.